# Список цифр в textBox или listBox

Tags: c#

Пишу небольшую прогу. Смысл ее такой: есть textBox, в который я вствляю в столбик цифры: целые и с плавающей точкой. И нужно посчитать их сумму. Перебираю цифры с помощью **for**. Все бы ничего, но я так и не смог реализовать это. Какие-то цифры космические выбивал. В итоге пришлось это делать через listBox. Все получилось. Но тут есть неудобность: добавить в listBox цифры вручную, насколько я понял, нельзя.

```
          

double sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<listBox1.Items.Count;i++)
{
sum += Convert.ToDouble(listBox1.Items[i]);
}
```

Подскажите пожалуста, как такое же на textBox сделать. И правильно ли будет?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-and-winforms

Comment: @iluxa1810 не через код должны добавляться цифры. А вручную.

Comment: Найдите символ, который разделяет два значения, например если вы говорите, что `в столбик`, то это наверное новая строка, а значит можно разбить строку например по `"\r\n"`, а значит получение ваших строк будет примерно следующим: `.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. Получив строковой массив, вам нужно его наверно конвертировать в цифры, например грубо если так брать, то можно сделать следующее: `.Select(int.Parse)`, вот у вас на руках уже будет массив из чисел, дальше смотрите сами, что нужно вам с ним делать. Сложить? Легко: `.Sum()`.

Comment: Во-первых, укажите, какой графический фреймворк используете. WinForms? Во-вторых, следовало показать свой код c TextBox. В-третьих, для ввода нескольких значений пользователем можно использовать DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        double sum = 0;
        string numbers = textBox1.Text;
        var tmp = numbers.Split(new Char[] {'\\', '\n', '\r'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(tmp[i]);
        }
```